# What does it mean when 5 year fixed is lower than 5 year variable

Tags: mortgage, canada, mortgage-rate

For the past 10 years, we've had 2 5-year variable rate mortgages.  We have more or less won the bet in the fixed vs. variable game.

In the past, the variable was always a lower rate than the fixed.  However, while doing my research I discovered that fixed is now cheaper than variable.  What does this indicate about rate prediction over the next few years?  Is this a prediction that the interest rates will drop?

Typical rate chart:
**5 Year Variable Mortgage 3.25%**
1 Year Fixed Mortgage 3.49%
2 Year Fixed Mortgage 2.74%
3 Year Fixed Mortgage 2.79%
4 Year Fixed Mortgage 2.94%
**5 Year Fixed Mortgage 2.89%**
7 Year Fixed Mortgage 2.99%
10 Year Fixed Mortgage 3.19%

Answer (score 9):

> What does this indicate about rate prediction over the next few years?

It indicates that the market believes that the near-term interest rate will drop below 2.89% (to bring the average down from 3.49% to 2.89%) over the next 5 years.

Comment: Also, establishment fees are typically higher for fixed interest rate products which may contribute to a lower interest rate.